# Can I add rigid foam to the cold side of a kneewall?

Tags: insulation

I have kneewalls and attic floor/1st floor ceiling that are insulated with R13 and then have plywood covering. The floor has plastic against the 1st floor ceiling "warm side". I'm considering adding insulation but leaning towards putting 2 inch rigid foam on top of the plywood on the kneewall and under the plywood on the floor.

This would be easier and save space compared to adding more framing and then adding more fiberglass or cellulose. I'm only concerned about condensation, etc. I've seen what I'm proposing done on a few videos etc but want to make sure this is ok.